# Cant load xib file from UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to load a xib file from my `UIViewController`.

In .h

```
UIView *myView;

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
```

In my .m

```
@synthesize myView;

if([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil]) { 
            [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.myView];

}
```

From the same `UIViewController` I load and remove xib files. I have used the same code in the above cases, and it worked. Its one particular xib file that seems to have the problem. I have checked, whether the window is nil. But its not. Cant figure out what the problem is.

Edit: Is it possible that `self` is getting released prematurely

Before loading this xib file I use the same code to load another xib file. And that works fine. I am trying to load the current xib file above this view.

Comment: Did you check the xib name? Sometimes we miss out small things causing big problems!

Comment: Have you checked your binding in IB?

Comment: I have rechecked the IB and bindings are all right. I am not getting any errors. Its just that the xib file(UIView) is not loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if([[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]) { 
            [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.myView];

}
```

I think the problem may be that "loadNibNamed" returns an NSArray of top-level objects.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make sure that your xib file has been added to the Copy Bundle Resources section of the target, in the Build Phases section. (And double check as well that it has been added to the Navigation menu resources).

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading this view over another `UIView`, and if that `UIView`is loaded correctly, then you can add this view as the subview of the `UIView`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to be the answer, though its working fine in my case.